# VS Code testing tab no longer finds tests

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

After upgrading from Flutter 2.5.0 to Flutter 2.5.1, the testing tab in VS Code no longer finds all the tests for any of my Flutter projects.  Instead, this is all I see:

[image: Testing tab example]

I've tried downgrading back to 2.5.0, but no luck.  Obviously, I can still use just use `flutter test` to run all the tests, but this isn't as nice as the testing UI that was previously available.  Other developers on my teams have also run into this problem.  I haven't seen any posts / info about it online or in the Flutter changelogs.  My VS Code version is the exact same from before this became an problem.  (VS Code version: 1.60.2)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a temporary fix.  But if you downgrade the dart extension in VS Code, then it will bring back the older testing which can find / run all the tests.

Open the extensions tab in VS Code -> gear icon -> install another version... -> 3.26.0.  After it finds the version, and you select it, you'll need to restart VS Code.  Then the old testing should be available.

[image]